# RTSP not working when using 3G connection, however it works when using WiFi

Tags: android, streaming, rtsp, android-wifi, rtsp-client

I have been working on application to play different radio rtsp, when I try it out on a tablet which only uses wifi(with Android 4.3), I can actually hear the radio stations fine. However when I test it on a mobile ( with Android 2.3 ), I cannot get any results using its 3G connection. However when I turn on the mobile's wifi, it works.

For instance, this rtsp will not work for both cases: rtsp://movil.mediastream.com.pe/av_rpp/audio01

What am I missing? why does it work with wifi and not on 3G? What can I do to make it work in Android 2.3 with its 3G? what are my alternatives to make the application work? Thanks in advance

This is the function I use to play a rtsp;

```
public void playUrl( Context context, String myUrl )
{
    if ( myMusicPlayer == null )    { 

        myMusicPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); 
        myMusicPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            myMusicPlayer.setDataSource( myUrl );

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d( TAG, "Argument error: " + e.getMessage() ); 
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d( TAG, "State error: " + e.getMessage() ); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d( TAG, "IO error: " + e.getMessage() ); 
        } finally {
            Log.d( TAG, "myMusicPlayer with url: " + myUrl + " created from playUrl()" ); 

            try {
                myMusicPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Log.d( TAG, "myMusicPlayer with url: " + myUrl + " prepared from playUrl()" ); 

                isPaused = false;
                isStopped = false;

                myMusicPlayer.setVolume( 0.4f, 0.4f ); 
                myMusicPlayer.start(); 
            }

        }

    }   // end of if statement

}
```

This is what I got from Android shark when using one of the rtsp that does not work in 3G:

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000    25.27.123.52          68.28.68.132          DNS      84     Standard query A rtsp.vog.sprintpcs.com

Frame 1: 84 bytes on wire (672 bits), 84 bytes captured (672 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.68.132 (68.28.68.132)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 2015 (2015), Dst Port: domain (53)
Domain Name System (query)

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 0.885515    68.28.68.132          25.27.123.52          DNS      130    Standard query response A 68.28.31.20

Frame 2: 130 bytes on wire (1040 bits), 130 bytes captured (1040 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.68.132 (68.28.68.132), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: domain (53), Dst Port: 2015 (2015)
Domain Name System (response)

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 0.889796    25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           TCP      76     51864 > rtsp [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1432 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=68282 TSecr=0 WS=2

Frame 3: 76 bytes on wire (608 bits), 76 bytes captured (608 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51864 (51864), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 1.369477    68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          TCP      80     rtsp > 51864 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=4296 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=1 TSval=1377591467 TSecr=68282 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 4: 80 bytes on wire (640 bits), 80 bytes captured (640 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51864 (51864), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 1.370102    25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           TCP      68     51864 > rtsp [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131070 Len=0 TSval=68379 TSecr=1377591467

Frame 5: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51864 (51864), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      6 1.372055    25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           RTSP     581    OPTIONS rtsp://movil.mediastream.com.pe/av_rpp/audio01 RTSP/1.0

Frame 6: 581 bytes on wire (4648 bits), 581 bytes captured (4648 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51864 (51864), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 513
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      7 2.074345    68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          TCP      68     rtsp > 51864 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=514 Win=4809 Len=0 TSval=1377592153 TSecr=68379

Frame 7: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51864 (51864), Seq: 1, Ack: 514, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      8 2.074776    25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           RTSP     448    DESCRIBE rtsp://movil.mediastream.com.pe/av_rpp/audio01 RTSP/1.0

Frame 8: 448 bytes on wire (3584 bits), 448 bytes captured (3584 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51864 (51864), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 514, Ack: 1, Len: 380
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      9 2.169196    25.27.123.52          50.22.213.141         SSL      69     [Malformed Packet]

Frame 9: 69 bytes on wire (552 bits), 69 bytes captured (552 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 50.22.213.141 (50.22.213.141)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 39306 (39306), Dst Port: https (443), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 1
Secure Sockets Layer
[Malformed Packet: SSL]

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     10 2.419297    68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          RTSP     329    Reply: RTSP/1.0 200 OK

Frame 10: 329 bytes on wire (2632 bits), 329 bytes captured (2632 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51864 (51864), Seq: 1, Ack: 894, Len: 261
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     11 2.419766    25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           TCP      68     51864 > rtsp [ACK] Seq=894 Ack=262 Win=130812 Len=0 TSval=68589 TSecr=1377592715

Frame 11: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51864 (51864), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 894, Ack: 262, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     12 2.509346    50.22.213.141         25.27.123.52          TCP      68     https > 39306 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2 Win=513 Len=0 TSval=3587254903 TSecr=68539

Frame 12: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 50.22.213.141 (50.22.213.141), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: https (443), Dst Port: 39306 (39306), Seq: 1, Ack: 2, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     13 2.510210    25.27.123.52          50.22.213.141         SSL      89     Continuation Data

Frame 13: 89 bytes on wire (712 bits), 89 bytes captured (712 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 50.22.213.141 (50.22.213.141)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 39306 (39306), Dst Port: https (443), Seq: 2, Ack: 1, Len: 21
Secure Sockets Layer

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     14 2.819330    68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          RTSP/SDP 740    Reply: RTSP/1.0 200 OK, with session description

Frame 14: 740 bytes on wire (5920 bits), 740 bytes captured (5920 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51864 (51864), Seq: 262, Ack: 894, Len: 672
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     15 2.819649    25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           TCP      68     51864 > rtsp [ACK] Seq=894 Ack=934 Win=130140 Len=0 TSval=68669 TSecr=1377592998

Frame 15: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51864 (51864), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 894, Ack: 934, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     16 2.914297    50.22.213.141         25.27.123.52          SSL      78     Continuation Data

Frame 16: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 50.22.213.141 (50.22.213.141), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: https (443), Dst Port: 39306 (39306), Seq: 1, Ack: 23, Len: 10
Secure Sockets Layer

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     17 2.928645    25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           RTSP     502    SETUP rtsp://movil.mediastream.com.pe/av_rpp/audio01/trackID=1 RTSP/1.0

Frame 17: 502 bytes on wire (4016 bits), 502 bytes captured (4016 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51864 (51864), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 894, Ack: 934, Len: 434
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     18 2.938016    25.27.123.52          50.22.213.141         TCP      68     39306 > https [FIN, ACK] Seq=23 Ack=11 Win=65348 Len=0 TSval=68692 TSecr=3587255189

Frame 18: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 50.22.213.141 (50.22.213.141)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 39306 (39306), Dst Port: https (443), Seq: 23, Ack: 11, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     19 3.519708    50.22.213.141         25.27.123.52          TCP      68     https > 39306 [ACK] Seq=11 Ack=24 Win=513 Len=0 TSval=3587255676 TSecr=68692

Frame 19: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 50.22.213.141 (50.22.213.141), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: https (443), Dst Port: 39306 (39306), Seq: 11, Ack: 24, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     20 3.519727    50.22.213.141         25.27.123.52          TCP      68     https > 39306 [FIN, ACK] Seq=11 Ack=24 Win=513 Len=0 TSval=3587255676 TSecr=68692

Frame 20: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 50.22.213.141 (50.22.213.141), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: https (443), Dst Port: 39306 (39306), Seq: 11, Ack: 24, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     21 3.520178    25.27.123.52          50.22.213.141         TCP      68     39306 > https [ACK] Seq=24 Ack=12 Win=65348 Len=0 TSval=68809 TSecr=3587255676

Frame 21: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 50.22.213.141 (50.22.213.141)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 39306 (39306), Dst Port: https (443), Seq: 24, Ack: 12, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     22 3.539004    68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          TCP      68     rtsp > 51864 [ACK] Seq=934 Ack=1328 Win=5623 Len=0 TSval=1377593667 TSecr=68690

Frame 22: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51864 (51864), Seq: 934, Ack: 1328, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     23 3.539010    68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          RTSP     192    Reply: RTSP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error

Frame 23: 192 bytes on wire (1536 bits), 192 bytes captured (1536 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51864 (51864), Seq: 934, Ack: 1328, Len: 124
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     24 3.539159    25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           TCP      68     51864 > rtsp [ACK] Seq=1328 Ack=1058 Win=130016 Len=0 TSval=68813 TSecr=1377593689

Frame 24: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51864 (51864), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 1328, Ack: 1058, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     25 3.543981    68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          TCP      68     rtsp > 51864 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1058 Ack=1328 Win=5623 Len=0 TSval=1377593731 TSecr=68690

Frame 25: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51864 (51864), Seq: 1058, Ack: 1328, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     26 3.584053    25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           TCP      68     51864 > rtsp [ACK] Seq=1328 Ack=1059 Win=130016 Len=0 TSval=68822 TSecr=1377593731

Frame 26: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51864 (51864), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 1328, Ack: 1059, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     27 3.590624    25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           TCP      68     51864 > rtsp [FIN, ACK] Seq=1328 Ack=1059 Win=130016 Len=0 TSval=68823 TSecr=1377593731

Frame 27: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51864 (51864), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 1328, Ack: 1059, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     28 3.874756    68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          TCP      68     rtsp > 51864 [ACK] Seq=1059 Ack=1329 Win=5623 Len=0 TSval=1377594162 TSecr=68823

Frame 28: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51864 (51864), Seq: 1059, Ack: 1329, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     29 17.501055   25.27.123.52          68.28.68.132          DNS      86
```

And this is the pcap file that I get for one rtsp that works for both wifi and 3G:

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000    107.20.164.42         25.27.123.52          TCP      56     http > 53888 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=4824 Len=0

Frame 1: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 107.20.164.42 (107.20.164.42), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: http (80), Dst Port: 53888 (53888), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 10.627568   25.27.123.52          68.28.68.132          DNS      84     Standard query A rtsp.vog.sprintpcs.com

Frame 2: 84 bytes on wire (672 bits), 84 bytes captured (672 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.68.132 (68.28.68.132)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 61420 (61420), Dst Port: domain (53)
Domain Name System (query)

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 11.085971   68.28.68.132          25.27.123.52          DNS      130    Standard query response A 68.28.31.20

Frame 3: 130 bytes on wire (1040 bits), 130 bytes captured (1040 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.68.132 (68.28.68.132), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: domain (53), Dst Port: 61420 (61420)
Domain Name System (response)

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 11.088280   25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           TCP      76     51402 > rtsp [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1432 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=280424 TSecr=0 WS=2

Frame 4: 76 bytes on wire (608 bits), 76 bytes captured (608 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51402 (51402), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 11.184782   68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          TCP      80     rtsp > 51402 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=4296 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=1 TSval=1378652387 TSecr=280424 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 5: 80 bytes on wire (640 bits), 80 bytes captured (640 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51402 (51402), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      6 11.185299   25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           TCP      68     51402 > rtsp [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131070 Len=0 TSval=280444 TSecr=1378652387

Frame 6: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51402 (51402), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      7 11.186806   25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           RTSP     576    OPTIONS rtsp://67.212.178.250/live/lakalle.stream RTSP/1.0

Frame 7: 576 bytes on wire (4608 bits), 576 bytes captured (4608 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51402 (51402), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 508
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      8 11.405223   68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          RTSP     353    Reply: RTSP/1.0 200 OK

Frame 8: 353 bytes on wire (2824 bits), 353 bytes captured (2824 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51402 (51402), Seq: 1, Ack: 509, Len: 285
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      9 11.405676   25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           RTSP     443    DESCRIBE rtsp://67.212.178.250/live/lakalle.stream RTSP/1.0

Frame 9: 443 bytes on wire (3544 bits), 443 bytes captured (3544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51402 (51402), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 509, Ack: 286, Len: 375
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     10 11.734520   68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          RTSP/SDP 757    Reply: RTSP/1.0 200 OK, with session description

Frame 10: 757 bytes on wire (6056 bits), 757 bytes captured (6056 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51402 (51402), Seq: 286, Ack: 884, Len: 689
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     11 11.774576   25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           TCP      68     51402 > rtsp [ACK] Seq=884 Ack=975 Win=130100 Len=0 TSval=280562 TSecr=1378652931

Frame 11: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51402 (51402), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 884, Ack: 975, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     12 11.775863   25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           RTSP     499    SETUP rtsp://67.212.178.250/live/lakalle.stream/trackID=1 RTSP/1.0

Frame 12: 499 bytes on wire (3992 bits), 499 bytes captured (3992 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51402 (51402), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 884, Ack: 975, Len: 431
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     13 11.919571   68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          RTSP     424    Reply: RTSP/1.0 200 OK

Frame 13: 424 bytes on wire (3392 bits), 424 bytes captured (3392 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51402 (51402), Seq: 975, Ack: 1315, Len: 356
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     14 11.919788   25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           TCP      68     51402 > rtsp [ACK] Seq=1315 Ack=1331 Win=129744 Len=0 TSval=280591 TSecr=1378653113

Frame 14: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51402 (51402), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 1315, Ack: 1331, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     15 12.242948   25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           RTP      56     Unknown RTP version 0

Frame 15: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 11960 (11960), Dst Port: afs3-kaserver (7004)
Real-Time Transport Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     16 12.246630   25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           RTSP     432    PLAY rtsp://67.212.178.250/live/lakalle.stream RTSP/1.0

Frame 16: 432 bytes on wire (3456 bits), 432 bytes captured (3456 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51402 (51402), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 1315, Ack: 1331, Len: 364
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     17 12.255425   25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           RTP      56     Unknown RTP version 0

Frame 17: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 11960 (11960), Dst Port: afs3-kaserver (7004)
Real-Time Transport Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     18 12.256874   25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           RTP      56     Unknown RTP version 0

Frame 18: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 11960 (11960), Dst Port: afs3-kaserver (7004)
Real-Time Transport Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     19 12.425122   68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          RTSP     364    Reply: RTSP/1.0 200 OK

Frame 19: 364 bytes on wire (2912 bits), 364 bytes captured (2912 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20), Dst: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: rtsp (554), Dst Port: 51402 (51402), Seq: 1331, Ack: 1679, Len: 296
Real Time Streaming Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     20 12.425476   25.27.123.52          68.28.31.20           TCP      68     51402 > rtsp [ACK] Seq=1679 Ack=1627 Win=129448 Len=0 TSval=280692 TSecr=1378653592

Frame 20: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 25.27.123.52 (25.27.123.52), Dst: 68.28.31.20 (68.28.31.20)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51402 (51402), Dst Port: rtsp (554), Seq: 1679, Ack: 1627, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     21 12.494663   68.28.31.20           25.27.123.52          RTCP     72     Sender Report
```

Comment: Can you share .pcap file? For Android you can capture packets by using "shark" tool. Capture the RTSP packets, save the file and open it on your desktop using wireshark/ethereal. Please post complete RTSP request and responses.

Comment: I have tried to use the 'shark' application, however it gives me an error saying: "Can't execute Root startup Sequence. Do you have root". Is there another application I need to install to use shark?

Comment: I was able to root my device and make shark sniff the packets I have edited my question and added the pcap file, thanks

Comment: You are clearly getting "RTSP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error" in response to SETUP. It can be due to wrong header fields in your SETUP request or server has not enough information/capability to send reply to SETUP request thus issuing simply "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: is there anything I can do from my end, meaning if I can change or add something in my MediaPlayer code to make it work. Also why do I get this error on 3G and not in WiFi, knowing this is there a workaround I can apply here

Comment: I sniffed both cases again, here are the links for the 2 entire pcap files: http://pastebin.com/9UWaQS8s and http://pastebin.com/iD41V6Pp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work with a third party app? Chances are that your mobile provider is filtering your connection, so RTP packets are not getting through. If that is the case, there is really nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Well I do not think it has to do with the carrier, I have tried this rtsp: "rtsp://67.212.178.250/live/lakalle.stream", and it works fine in wifi and 3G, however this one: "rtsp://movil.mediastream.com.pe/av_rpp/audio01" only works in wifi not in 3G

Comment: These are other urls that I can play with MediaPlayer using WiFi, but not 3G: http://76.10.222.35:9200/;stream.nsv and http://mediastream.pe/crp/spot/cuNa.mp3

Comment: all rtsp and mp3 links work when I'm using a WiFi connection, but not with 3G. I have not tried them out with other applications since this is the only application I'm working on that uses these links

Comment: there are other applications like tunein that play the same radios, I'm guessing that they are able to use their rtsp links, not sure though how to make it work for 3G connections

Comment: consider switching protocols because RTSP over 3G may prove to be a chronically complex headache. i see your audio only , but maybe u take a look at dash-js ....
http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?page_id=746
try the samples in chrome after u turn on the video flag in chrome

Comment: cannot do no that, the only format available to me is rtsp and online files like: mediastream.pe/crp/spot/cuNa.mp3 and 76.10.222.35:9200/;stream.nsv

Answer (score 0):

in your first pcap file ( the one missing any RTP packets in the dump ) its possible that the client & server did not agree on a TRANSPORT in the RTSP protocol. If you look at a typical rtsp conversation between the DESCRIBE and the SETUP, there should be agreement on transport which will cover IP addresses / ports for the binary data connection ( the audio stream ) that is NOT getting thru in the 3G pcap.

see #  149, #156  in this RTSP session [dump](http://snipplr.com/view/56509/youtube-rtsp-cli-request--audio-track-only/)

Maybe you will need to figure out how to get your pcap viewer to extract and or format the actual RTPS messages from the appropriate displacements in the RTSP packets you are dumping. That way, you can compare what is happening to a normal RTSP session like the one in the link provided.

Comment: These pcap files are much larger than what I posted on my question, is there any way to post the complete pcap files to better show you what is going on? thanks

Comment: you can use pastebin for big stuff .. give it an expire of a month or something

Comment: ok, got it, here are the links for the 2 pcap files: http://pastebin.com/9UWaQS8s and http://pastebin.com/iD41V6Pp